# Play MP3 by clicking button using HTML5Media or similar

Tags: javascript, html, mp3, html5-audio, mediaelement.js

I need to click a button to run an mp3. 
I'm using HTML5Media (http://html5media.info/) because it works in any browser and works on mobile devices.

But with it I can just put normal player and the player can not run when you click a button. 
How can I do this?

Remember that need a solution that works across mobile devices.

-

This is my code:

```
<audio controls preload> 
    <source src="scream.mp3"></source> 
    <source src="scream.ogg"></source> 
</audio>
```

Comment: post your code an let us see what happened while you using *html5media*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuing you want to create an *additional* button to control the audio, although the built in controls (displayed with the `controls`-attribute of the `audio`-tag) does have a pause/play-button. Try this:

```
<a href="javascript:playPause();">Play/Pause</a>
<audio controls preload>
    <source src="someUrl"></source>
</audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function playPause() {
        var song = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
        if (song.paused) song.play();
        else song.pause(); 
    }
</script>
```